# VBA Script working and now is not

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a very quick script for VBA that takes a spread sheet and organizes it appropriately. For some reason I have just tried using it and I get a user defined error at this loop:

```
Dim qu As Long

For j = i To 10 Step -1
    If Cells(j, 10) = "" Then
        qu = j - 1
        Do While Cells(qu, 10) = Cells(qu - 1, 10)
            Cells(qu, 11) = 10
            Cells(qu - 1, 11) = 10
            qu = qu - 1
        Loop
    Cells(j - 1, 11) = 10
    End If
Next j
```

The whole code looks like this:

```
Sub PopulateNF()
i = 10

Do While Cells(i, 2) <> ""
 i = i + 1
Loop

For k = 10 To i Step 1
    If Cells(k, 1) <> "" Then
        Cells(k, 10) = ""
    Else
        If InStr(1, Cells(k, 2), "Received") Then
            Cells(k, 10) = -1
        ElseIf InStr(1, Cells(k, 2), "Workflow") Then
            Cells(k, 10) = 0
        ElseIf InStr(1, Cells(k, 2), "Forwarded") Then
            Cells(k, 10) = 1
        ElseIf InStr(1, Cells(k, 2), "Review Response") Then
            Cells(k, 10) = 2
        ElseIf InStr(1, Cells(k, 2), "Responded and Closed") Then
            Cells(k, 10) = 4
        ElseIf InStr(1, Cells(k, 2), "Sent") Then
            Cells(k, 10) = 3
        ElseIf InStr(1, Cells(k, 2), "Sent and Closed") Then
            Cells(k, 10) = 3
        End If
    End If
Next k

Dim qu As Long

For j = i To 10 Step -1
    If Cells(j, 10) = "" Then
        qu = j - 1
        Do While Cells(qu, 10) = Cells(qu - 1, 10)
            Cells(qu, 11) = 10
            Cells(qu - 1, 11) = 10
            qu = qu - 1
        Loop
    Cells(j - 1, 11) = 10
    End If
Next j


For a = i To 10 Step -1
    If Cells(a, 1) <> "" Then
        Cells(a, 11) = 10
    End If
Next a


Const colA      As Long = 11
Dim lngRow      As Long
Dim lngLastRow  As Long

lngLastRow = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
lngRow = 10
Do While lngRow <= lngLastRow
    If Cells(lngRow, colA) = "" Then
        Cells(lngRow, 1).EntireRow.Delete
        lngLastRow = lngLastRow - 1
    Else: lngRow = lngRow + 1
    End If
Loop

d = 10

Do While Cells(d, 2) <> ""
 d = d + 1
Loop

For k = 6 To d Step 1
    If Cells(k, 1) = "" Then
        Cells(k, 1) = Cells(k, 6)
        Cells(k, 6) = ""
        Cells(k, 2) = Cells(k, 7)
        Cells(k, 7) = ""
        Cells(k, 3) = Cells(k - 1, 3)
        Cells(k, 4) = Cells(k - 1, 4)
        Cells(k, 5) = Cells(k - 1, 5)
        Cells(k, 6) = Cells(k - 1, 6)
        Cells(k, 7) = Cells(k - 1, 7)
        Cells(k, 8) = Cells(k - 1, 8)
        Cells(k, 9) = Cells(k - 1, 9)
    End If
Next k

Const colAN      As Long = 1
Dim lngRowN      As Long
Dim lngLastRowN  As Long

lngLastRowN = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
lngRowN = 9
Do While lngRowN <= lngLastRowN
    If Cells(lngRowN, colAN) = "" Then
        Cells(lngRowN, 1).EntireRow.Delete
        lngLastRowN = lngLastRowN - 1
    ElseIf InStr(1, Cells(lngRowN, colAN), "_") Then
        Cells(lngRowN, 1).EntireRow.Delete
        lngLastRowN = lngLastRowN - 1
    Else: lngRowN = lngRowN + 1
    End If
Loop

Range("a9").CurrentRegion.Sort key1:=Range("a9"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess

Range("D:D").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
Range("F:I").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"

Range("C:I").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
Range("a:a").VerticalAlignment = xlTop

Range("J:K").EntireColumn.Delete

Range("A:J").Font.Color = vbBlack

MsgBox ("Reformatting Complete")

End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In the VB Editor look under Tools>References  Are any flagged as "Missing" ?

Comment: They all seem to be available.

Comment: Code complie fine for me on Excle in office 2010. close the office and reopen then try it

Comment: What's the *exact* error message, and on which line?

Comment: @SammyB I made it `While Cells(qu, 10) = Cells(qu - 1, 10) and qu <> 2` which seems to have fixed my issue. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Stepping through the code looks like your loop doesn't know where to end.

Basically the line:

```
Do While Cells(qu, 10) = Cells(qu - 1, 10)
```

is never false and "qu-1" eventually becomes negative.

I'm not sure if this works with the greater bulk of your code, but you could try:

```
Do While qu <> 1
```

That should close your loop while still allowing you to modify cell values within the loop.

Comment: I am receiving Run - time error '1004'

Application - defined or object - defined error.